# What is the intersection point of the graphs of digamma and trigamma functions?

Tags: digamma-function, polygamma

We have the series expansions of digamma and trigamma functions for $x>0$,
$$\psi^{(0)}(x)=-\gamma-\frac1x+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac1k-\frac1{x+k})$$
and
$$\psi^{(1)}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+n)^2}$$
respectively. Looking at the graphs of these functions, I saw a unique intersection point. Graph of digamma function looks like a shifted
logarithm function and graph of trigamma looks like an hyperbola. İnspired from this I thought the intersection point must be close to the intersection of $y=\ln x-\gamma$ and $y=\frac1{x^{2}}$ which is $\approx 2.19$ for the $x$-coordinate. Note that the real value is $\approx 2.23$.

Questions: Can my guess be justified? Is there a literature for this intersection point? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Concerning bounds you may indeed use the [digamma inequalities as $\ln x - \frac{1}{x} \le \psi(x) \le \ln x - \frac{1}{2x}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Inequalities) and the [trigamma $\frac{x+\frac12}{x^2} \le \psi^{(1)}(x)\le \frac{x+1}{x^2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function#Trigamma_bounds_and_asymptote)

Comment: You can think of it as the minimum of $\ln(\Gamma(x))-\psi(x)$